# Firefox profile is missing or inaccessible (again) on macOS High Sierra after running CleanMyMac X

Tags: firefox

My Firefox install broke right after I first ran a version of **CleanMyMac X**. When trying to run, I get this error.

```
Your firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible mac.
```

To troubleshoot, I did the following:

1. I tried downloading the latest FireFox.

   ```
   /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --full-version

   Mozilla Firefox 79.0 20200720193547 20200720193547
   (MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6 (17G11023)))
   ```
2. I also checked these files.

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/ # If I rename this to a backup file, this get replaced on an attempted FF launch 
   ~/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/ # Doesn't exist
   ```

I've followed Mozilla's official guide for "How to run Firefox when your profile is missing or inaccessible". I've also combed through this [SO post](https://superuser.com/questions/1308160/mac-os-x-high-sierra-firefox-profile-is-missing-or-inaccessible#new-answer) to no avail.

- [How to run Firefox when your profile is missing or inaccessible](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-run-firefox-when-profile-missing-inaccessible)
- [MAC Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible. how to fix?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1152265#:%7E:text=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org,ownership%20of%20involved%20folders%2Ffiles.&text=If%20clearing%20the%20profiles.)

Has anyone solved this? Even while following the documentation, I get the same error window, regardless of the command that I run.

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --ProfileManager
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to update to FF 72.0.2 a while back. I'm on a Mac.
Solutions seem convoluted and difficult. see
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1281306

Hopefully you have a bootable backup of your computer with a Firefox version that was functional. If you do, you can copy FF profile & bookmarks

in ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox
Just option-copy the entire xxxxxx.default folder  and save it to a flash drive

Show all bookmarks
then under the star, pick Backup      and do a .json (addable to a new FF)

Now you need to find and download a version of Firefox

go here
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-firefox#firefox:mac:fx70
and use the box to pick the version one older than the one you want, then download the one you want.   Put that on the flash.

Back on your current computer

Copy the files you saved and put them in their right spots.

If this still fails to function, delete Firefox and all accoutrements. then install the downloaded installer, and repeat.

Good luck!